# WooCommerce phone field with country flag and code

Tags: css

I tried to configure the code to work like image 02 site rtl and code for sms otp verification for wordpress. Here is the code and the images:

[image]

[image]

```
 .intl-tel-input{position:relative;display:inline-block}.intl-tel-input *{box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box}.intl-tel-input .hide{display:none}.intl-tel-input .v-hide{visibility:hidden}.intl-tel-input input,.intl-tel-input input[type=tel],.intl-tel-input input[type=text]{position:relative;z-index:0;margin-top:0!important;margin-bottom:0!important;padding-right:36px;margin-right:0}.intl-tel-input .flag-container{position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;right:0;padding:1px}.intl-tel-input .selected-flag{z-index:1;position:relative;right:-280px;width:36px;height:100%;padding:0 0 0 8px}.intl-tel-input .selected-flag .iti-flag{position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;margin:auto}.intl-tel-input .selected-flag .iti-arrow{position:absolute;top:50%;margin-top:-2px;right:6px;width:0;height:0;border-left:3px solid transparent;border-right:3px solid transparent;border-top:4px solid #555}.intl-tel-input .selected-flag .iti-arrow.up{border-top:none;border-bottom:4px solid #555}.intl-tel-input .country-list{position:absolute;right:-285px;z-index:2;list-style:none;text-align:right;padding:0;margin:0 0 0 -1px;box-shadow:1px 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);background-color:#fff;border:1px solid #CCC;white-space:nowrap;max-height:200px;max-width:331px;overflow-y:scroll}.intl-tel-input .country-list .country.highlight,.intl-tel-input.allow-dropdown .flag-container:hover .selected-flag{background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.05)}.intl-tel-input .country-list.dropup{bottom:100%;margin-bottom:-1px}.intl-tel-input .country-list .flag-box{display:inline-block;width:20px}@media (max-width:500px){.intl-tel-input .country-list{white-space:normal}}.intl-tel-input .country-list .divider{padding-bottom:5px;margin-bottom:5px;border-bottom:1px solid #CCC}.intl-tel-input .country-list .country{padding:5px 10px}.intl-tel-input .country-list .country .dial-code{color:#999}.intl-tel-input .country-list .country-name,.intl-tel-input .country-list .dial-code,.intl-tel-input .country-list .flag-box{vertical-align:middle}.intl-tel-input .country-list .country-name,.intl-tel-input .country-list .flag-box{margin-right:6px}.intl-tel-input.allow-dropdown input,.intl-tel-input.allow-dropdown input[type=tel],.intl-tel-input.allow-dropdown input[type=text],.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code input,.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code input[type=tel],.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code input[type=text]{padding-right:6px;padding-left:52px;margin-left:0}.intl-tel-input.allow-dropdown .flag-container,.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code .flag-container{right:auto;left:0}.intl-tel-input.allow-dropdown .selected-flag,.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code .selected-flag{width:46px}.intl-tel-input.allow-dropdown .flag-container:hover{cursor:pointer}.intl-tel-input.allow-dropdown input[disabled]+.flag-container:hover,.intl-tel-input.allow-dropdown input[readonly]+.flag-container:hover{cursor:default}.intl-tel-input.allow-dropdown input[disabled]+.flag-container:hover .selected-flag,.intl-tel-input.allow-dropdown input[readonly]+.flag-container:hover .selected-flag{background-color:transparent}.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code .selected-flag{background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.05);display:table}.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code .selected-dial-code{display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;padding-left:28px}.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.iti-sdc-2 input,.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.iti-sdc-2 input[type=tel],.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.iti-sdc-2 input[type=text]{padding-left:66px}.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.iti-sdc-2 .selected-flag{width:60px}.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.allow-dropdown.iti-sdc-2 input,.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.allow-dropdown.iti-sdc-2 input[type=tel],.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.allow-dropdown.iti-sdc-2 input[type=text]{padding-left:76px}.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.allow-dropdown.iti-sdc-2 .selected-flag{width:70px}.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.iti-sdc-3 input,.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.iti-sdc-3 input[type=tel],.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.iti-sdc-3 input[type=text]{padding-left:74px}.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.iti-sdc-3 .selected-flag{width:68px}.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.allow-dropdown.iti-sdc-3 input,.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.allow-dropdown.iti-sdc-3 input[type=tel],.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.allow-dropdown.iti-sdc-3 input[type=text]{padding-left:84px}.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.allow-dropdown.iti-sdc-3 .selected-flag{width:78px}.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.iti-sdc-4 input,.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.iti-sdc-4 input[type=tel],.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.iti-sdc-4 input[type=text]{padding-left:82px}.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.iti-sdc-4 .selected-flag{width:76px}.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.allow-dropdown.iti-sdc-4 input,.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.allow-dropdown.iti-sdc-4 input[type=tel],.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.allow-dropdown.iti-sdc-4 input[type=text]{padding-left:92px}.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.allow-dropdown.iti-sdc-4 .selected-flag{width:86px}.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.iti-sdc-5 input,.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.iti-sdc-5 input[type=tel],.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.iti-sdc-5 input[type=text]{padding-left:90px}.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.iti-sdc-5 .selected-flag{width:84px}.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.allow-dropdown.iti-sdc-5 input,.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.allow-dropdown.iti-sdc-5 input[type=tel],.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.allow-dropdown.iti-sdc-5 input[type=text]{padding-left:100px}.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.allow-dropdown.iti-sdc-5 .selected-flag{width:94px}.intl-tel-input.iti-container{position:absolute;top:-1000px;left:-1000px;z-index:1060;padding:1px}.intl-tel-input.iti-container:hover{cursor:pointer}.iti-mobile .intl-tel-input.iti-container{top:30px;bottom:30px;left:30px;right:30px;position:fixed}.iti-mobile .intl-tel-input .country-list{max-height:100%;width:100%}.iti-mobile .intl-tel-input .country-list .country{padding:10px;line-height:1.5em}.iti-flag{width:20px}.iti-flag.be{width:18px}.iti-flag.ch{width:15px}.iti-flag.mc{width:19px}.iti-flag.ne{width:18px}.iti-flag.ac{height:10px;background-position:0 0}.iti-flag.ad{height:14px;background-position:-22px 0}.iti-flag.ae{height:10px;background-position:-44px 0}.iti-flag.af{height:14px;background-position:-66px 0}.iti-flag.ag{height:14px;background-position:-88px 0}.iti-flag.ai{height:10px;background-position:-110px 0}.iti-flag.al{height:15px;background-position:-132px 0}.iti-flag.am{height:10px;background-position:-154px 0}.iti-flag.ao{height:14px;background-position:-176px 0}.iti-flag.aq{height:14px;background-position:-198px 0}.iti-flag.ar{height:13px;background-position:-220px 0}.iti-flag.as{height:10px;background-position:-242px 0}.iti-flag.at{height:14px;background-position:-264px 0}.iti-flag.au{height:10px;background-position:-286px 0}.iti-flag.aw{height:14px;background-position:-308px 0}.iti-flag.ax{height:13px;background-position:-330px 0}.iti-flag.az{height:10px;background-position:-352px 0}.iti-flag.ba{height:10px;background-position:-374px 0}.iti-flag.bb{height:14px;background-position:-396px 0}.iti-flag.bd{height:12px;background-position:-418px 0}.iti-flag.be{height:15px;background-position:-440px 0}.iti-flag.bf{height:14px;background-position:-460px 0}.iti-flag.bg{height:12px;background-position:-482px 0}.iti-flag.bh{height:12px;background-position:-504px 0}.iti-flag.bi{height:12px;background-position:-526px 0}.iti-flag.bj{height:14px;background-position:-548px 0}.iti-flag.bl{height:14px;background-position:-570px 0}.iti-flag.bm{height:10px;background-position:-592px 0}.iti-flag.bn{height:10px;background-position:-614px 0}.iti-flag.bo{height:14px;background-position:-636px 0}.iti-flag.bq{height:14px;background-position:-658px 0}.iti-flag.br{height:14px;background-position:-680px 0}.iti-flag.bs{height:10px;background-position:-702px 0}.iti-flag.bt{height:14px;background-position:-724px 0}.iti-flag.bv{height:15px;background-position:-746px 0}.iti-flag.bw{height:14px;background-position:-768px 0}.iti-flag.by{height:10px;background-position:-790px 0}.iti-flag.bz{height:14px;background-position:-812px 0}.iti-flag.ca{height:10px;background-position:-834px 0}.iti-flag.cc{height:10px;background-position:-856px 0}.iti-flag.cd{height:15px;background-position:-878px 0}.iti-flag.cf{height:14px;background-position:-900px 0}.iti-flag.cg{height:14px;background-position:-922px 0}.iti-flag.ch{height:15px;background-position:-944px 0}.iti-flag.ci{height:14px;background-position:-961px 0}.iti-flag.ck{height:10px;background-position:-983px 0}.iti-flag.cl{height:14px;background-position:-1005px 0}.iti-flag.cm{height:14px;background-position:-1027px 0}.iti-flag.cn{height:14px;background-position:-1049px 0}.iti-flag.co{height:14px;background-position:-1071px 0}.iti-flag.cp{height:14px;background-position:-1093px 0}.iti-flag.cr{height:12px;background-position:-1115px 0}.iti-flag.cu{height:10px;background-position:-1137px 0}.iti-flag.cv{height:12px;background-position:-1159px 0}.iti-flag.cw{height:14px;background-position:-1181px 0}.iti-flag.cx{height:10px;background-position:-1203px 0}.iti-flag.cy{height:13px;background-position:-1225px 0}.iti-flag.cz{height:14px;background-position:-1247px 0}.iti-flag.de{height:12px;background-position:-1269px 0}.iti-flag.dg{height:10px;background-position:-1291px 0}.iti-flag.dj{height:14px;background-position:-1313px 0}.iti-flag.dk{height:15px;background-position:-1335px 0}.iti-flag.dm{height:10px;background-position:-1357px 0}.iti-flag.do{height:13px;background-position:-1379px 0}.iti-flag.dz{height:14px;background-position:-1401px 0}.iti-flag.ea{height:14px;background-position:-1423px 0}.iti-flag.ec{height:14px;background-position:-1445px 0}.iti-flag.ee{height:13px;background-position:-1467px 0}.iti-flag.eg{height:14px;background-position:-1489px 0}.iti-flag.eh{height:10px;background-position:-1511px 0}.iti-flag.er{height:10px;background-position:-1533px 0}.iti-flag.es{height:14px;background-position:-1555px 0}.iti-flag.et{height:10px;background-position:-1577px 0}.iti-flag.eu{height:14px;background-position:-1599px 0}.iti-flag.fi{height:12px;background-position:-1621px 0}.iti-flag.fj{height:10px;background-position:-1643px 0}.iti-flag.fk{height:10px;background-position:-1665px 0}.iti-flag.fm{height:11px;background-position:-1687px 0}.iti-flag.fo{height:15px;background-position:-1709px 0}.iti-flag.fr{height:14px;background-position:-1731px 0}.iti-flag.ga{height:15px;background-position:-1753px 0}.iti-flag.gb{height:10px;background-position:-1775px 0}.iti-flag.gd{height:12px;background-position:-1797px 0}.iti-flag.ge{height:14px;background-position:-1819px 0}.iti-flag.gf{height:14px;background-position:-1841px 0}.iti-flag.gg{height:14px;background-position:-1863px 0}.iti-flag.gh{height:14px;background-position:-1885px 0}.iti-flag.gi{height:10px;background-position:-1907px 0}.iti-flag.gl{height:14px;background-position:-1929px 0}.iti-flag.gm{height:14px;background-position:-1951px 0}.iti-flag.gn{height:14px;background-position:-1973px 0}.iti-flag.gp{height:14px;background-position:-1995px 0}.iti-flag.gq{height:14px;background-position:-2017px 0}.iti-flag.gr{height:14px;background-position:-2039px 0}.iti-flag.gs{height:10px;background-position:-2061px 0}.iti-flag.gt{height:13px;background-position:-2083px 0}.iti-flag.gu{height:11px;background-position:-2105px 0}.iti-flag.gw{height:10px;background-position:-2127px 0}.iti-flag.gy{height:12px;background-position:-2149px 0}.iti-flag.hk{height:14px;background-position:-2171px 0}.iti-flag.hm{height:10px;background-position:-2193px 0}.iti-flag.hn{height:10px;background-position:-2215px 0}.iti-flag.hr{height:10px;background-position:-2237px 0}.iti-flag.ht{height:12px;background-position:-2259px 0}.iti-flag.hu{height:10px;background-position:-2281px 0}.iti-flag.ic{height:14px;background-position:-2303px 0}.iti-flag.id{height:14px;background-position:-2325px 0}.iti-flag.ie{height:10px;background-position:-2347px 0}.iti-flag.il{height:15px;background-position:-2369px 0}.iti-flag.im{height:10px;background-position:-2391px 0}.iti-flag.in{height:14px;background-position:-2413px 0}.iti-flag.io{height:10px;background-position:-2435px 0}.iti-flag.iq{height:14px;background-position:-2457px 0}.iti-flag.ir{height:12px;background-position:-2479px 0}.iti-flag.is{height:15px;background-position:-2501px 0}.iti-flag.it{height:14px;background-position:-2523px 0}.iti-flag.je{height:12px;background-position:-2545px 0}.iti-flag.jm{height:10px;background-position:-2567px 0}.iti-flag.jo{height:10px;background-position:-2589px 0}.iti-flag.jp{height:14px;background-position:-2611px 0}.iti-flag.ke{height:14px;background-position:-2633px 0}.iti-flag.kg{height:12px;background-position:-2655px 0}.iti-flag.kh{height:13px;background-position:-2677px 0}.iti-flag.ki{height:10px;background-position:-2699px 0}.iti-flag.km{height:12px;background-position:-2721px 0}.iti-flag.kn{height:14px;background-position:-2743px 0}.iti-flag.kp{height:10px;background-position:-2765px 0}.iti-flag.kr{height:14px;background-position:-2787px 0}.iti-flag.kw{height:10px;background-position:-2809px 0}.iti-flag.ky{height:10px;background-position:-2831px 0}.iti-flag.kz{height:10px;background-position:-2853px 0}.iti-flag.la{height:14px;background-position:-2875px 0}.iti-flag.lb{height:14px;background-position:-2897px 0}.iti-flag.lc{height:10px;background-position:-2919px 0}.iti-flag.li{height:12px;background-position:-2941px 0}.iti-flag.lk{height:10px;background-position:-2963px 0}.iti-flag.lr{height:11px;background-position:-2985px 0}.iti-flag.ls{height:14px;background-position:-3007px 0}.iti-flag.lt{height:12px;background-position:-3029px 0}.iti-flag.lu{height:12px;background-position:-3051px 0}.iti-flag.lv{height:10px;background-position:-3073px 0}.iti-flag.ly{height:10px;background-position:-3095px 0}.iti-flag.ma{height:14px;background-position:-3117px 0}.iti-flag.mc{height:15px;background-position:-3139px 0}.iti-flag.md{height:10px;background-position:-3160px 0}.iti-flag.me{height:10px;background-position:-3182px 0}.iti-flag.mf{height:14px;background-position:-3204px 0}.iti-flag.mg{height:14px;background-position:-3226px 0}.iti-flag.mh{height:11px;background-position:-3248px 0}.iti-flag.mk{height:10px;background-position:-3270px 0}.iti-flag.ml{height:14px;background-position:-3292px 0}.iti-flag.mm{height:14px;background-position:-3314px 0}.iti-flag.mn{height:10px;background-position:-3336px 0}.iti-flag.mo{height:14px;background-position:-3358px 0}.iti-flag.mp{height:10px;background-position:-3380px 0}.iti-flag.mq{height:14px;background-position:-3402px 0}.iti-flag.mr{height:14px;background-position:-3424px 0}.iti-flag.ms{height:10px;background-position:-3446px 0}.iti-flag.mt{height:14px;background-position:-3468px 0}.iti-flag.mu{height:14px;background-position:-3490px 0}.iti-flag.mv{height:14px;background-position:-3512px 0}.iti-flag.mw{height:14px;background-position:-3534px 0}.iti-flag.mx{height:12px;background-position:-3556px 0}.iti-flag.my{height:10px;background-position:-3578px 0}.iti-flag.mz{height:14px;background-position:-3600px 0}.iti-flag.na{height:14px;background-position:-3622px 0}.iti-flag.nc{height:10px;background-position:-3644px 0}.iti-flag.ne{height:15px;background-position:-3666px 0}.iti-flag.nf{height:10px;background-position:-3686px 0}.iti-flag.ng{height:10px;background-position:-3708px 0}.iti-flag.ni{height:12px;background-position:-3730px 0}.iti-flag.nl{height:14px;background-position:-3752px 0}.iti-flag.no{height:15px;background-position:-3774px 0}.iti-flag.np{width:13px;height:15px;background-position:-3796px 0}.iti-flag.nr{height:10px;background-position:-3811px 0}.iti-flag.nu{height:10px;background-position:-3833px 0}.iti-flag.nz{height:10px;background-position:-3855px 0}.iti-flag.om{height:10px;background-position:-3877px 0}.iti-flag.pa{height:14px;background-position:-3899px 0}.iti-flag.pe{height:14px;background-position:-3921px 0}.iti-flag.pf{height:14px;background-position:-3943px 0}.iti-flag.pg{height:15px;background-position:-3965px 0}.iti-flag.ph{height:10px;background-position:-3987px 0}.iti-flag.pk{height:14px;background-position:-4009px 0}.iti-flag.pl{height:13px;background-position:-4031px 0}.iti-flag.pm{height:14px;background-position:-4053px 0}.iti-flag.pn{height:10px;background-position:-4075px 0}.iti-flag.pr{height:14px;background-position:-4097px 0}.iti-flag.ps{height:10px;background-position:-4119px 0}.iti-flag.pt{height:14px;background-position:-4141px 0}.iti-flag.pw{height:13px;background-position:-4163px 0}.iti-flag.py{height:11px;background-position:-4185px 0}.iti-flag.qa{height:8px;background-position:-4207px 0}.iti-flag.re{height:14px;background-position:-4229px 0}.iti-flag.ro{height:14px;background-position:-4251px 0}.iti-flag.rs{height:14px;background-position:-4273px 0}.iti-flag.ru{height:14px;background-position:-4295px 0}.iti-flag.rw{height:14px;background-position:-4317px 0}.iti-flag.sa{height:14px;background-position:-4339px 0}.iti-flag.sb{height:10px;background-position:-4361px 0}.iti-flag.sc{height:10px;background-position:-4383px 0}.iti-flag.sd{height:10px;background-position:-4405px 0}.iti-flag.se{height:13px;background-position:-4427px 0}.iti-flag.sg{height:14px;background-position:-4449px 0}.iti-flag.sh{height:10px;background-position:-4471px 0}.iti-flag.si{height:10px;background-position:-4493px 0}.iti-flag.sj{height:15px;background-position:-4515px 0}.iti-flag.sk{height:14px;background-position:-4537px 0}.iti-flag.sl{height:14px;background-position:-4559px 0}.iti-flag.sm{height:15px;background-position:-4581px 0}.iti-flag.sn{height:14px;background-position:-4603px 0}.iti-flag.so{height:14px;background-position:-4625px 0}.iti-flag.sr{height:14px;background-position:-4647px 0}.iti-flag.ss{height:10px;background-position:-4669px 0}.iti-flag.st{height:10px;background-position:-4691px 0}.iti-flag.sv{height:12px;background-position:-4713px 0}.iti-flag.sx{height:14px;background-position:-4735px 0}.iti-flag.sy{height:14px;background-position:-4757px 0}.iti-flag.sz{height:14px;background-position:-4779px 0}.iti-flag.ta{height:10px;background-position:-4801px 0}.iti-flag.tc{height:10px;background-position:-4823px 0}.iti-flag.td{height:14px;background-position:-4845px 0}.iti-flag.tf{height:14px;background-position:-4867px 0}.iti-flag.tg{height:13px;background-position:-4889px 0}.iti-flag.th{height:14px;background-position:-4911px 0}.iti-flag.tj{height:10px;background-position:-4933px 0}.iti-flag.tk{height:10px;background-position:-4955px 0}.iti-flag.tl{height:10px;background-position:-4977px 0}.iti-flag.tm{height:14px;background-position:-4999px 0}.iti-flag.tn{height:14px;background-position:-5021px 0}.iti-flag.to{height:10px;background-position:-5043px 0}.iti-flag.tr{height:14px;background-position:-5065px 0}.iti-flag.tt{height:12px;background-position:-5087px 0}.iti-flag.tv{height:10px;background-position:-5109px 0}.iti-flag.tw{height:14px;background-position:-5131px 0}.iti-flag.tz{height:14px;background-position:-5153px 0}.iti-flag.ua{height:14px;background-position:-5175px 0}.iti-flag.ug{height:14px;background-position:-5197px 0}.iti-flag.um{height:11px;background-position:-5219px 0}.iti-flag.us{height:11px;background-position:-5241px 0}.iti-flag.uy{height:14px;background-position:-5263px 0}.iti-flag.uz{height:10px;background-position:-5285px 0}.iti-flag.va{width:15px;height:15px;background-position:-5307px 0}.iti-flag.vc{height:14px;background-position:-5324px 0}.iti-flag.ve{height:14px;background-position:-5346px 0}.iti-flag.vg{height:10px;background-position:-5368px 0}.iti-flag.vi{height:14px;background-position:-5390px 0}.iti-flag.vn{height:14px;background-position:-5412px 0}.iti-flag.vu{height:12px;background-position:-5434px 0}.iti-flag.wf{height:14px;background-position:-5456px 0}.iti-flag.ws{height:10px;background-position:-5478px 0}.iti-flag.xk{height:15px;background-position:-5500px 0}.iti-flag.ye{height:14px;background-position:-5522px 0}.iti-flag.yt{height:14px;background-position:-5544px 0}.iti-flag.za{height:14px;background-position:-5566px 0}.iti-flag.zm{height:14px;background-position:-5588px 0}.iti-flag.zw{height:10px;background-position:-5610px 0}.iti-flag{height:15px;box-shadow:0 0 1px 0 #888;background-image:url(../images/flags.png);background-repeat:no-repeat;background-color:#DBDBDB;background-position:20px 0}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2),only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio:2),only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio:2 / 1),only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio:2),only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi),only screen and (min-resolution:2dppx){.iti-flag{background-size:5630px 15px;background-image:url(../images/flags@2x.png)}}.iti-flag.np{background-color:transparent}
```

Comment: Could you kindly give more details on the problem, and also format the code in a way that it's actually readable?

Comment: thanks you, can u please check out my answer i add image and the code thanks

Comment: Looks like you have only the css code attached. Please provide a complete sample (html, css and js if needed), else it's not possible to give feedback.

Answer (score 0):

if you see the attached image u will find the flag image in left and code in right i wanna both the flag and code to appear in right
the css file name intlTelInput.css

```css
.intl-tel-input{position:relative;display:inline-block}.intl-tel-input *{box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box}.intl-tel-input .hide{display:none}.intl-tel-input .v-hide{visibility:hidden}.intl-tel-input input,.intl-tel-input input[type=tel],.intl-tel-input input[type=text]{position:relative;z-index:0;margin-top:0!important;margin-bottom:0!important;padding-right:36px;margin-right:0}.intl-tel-input .flag-container{position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;right:0;padding:1px}.intl-tel-input .selected-flag{z-index:1;position:relative;width:36px;height:100%;padding:0 0 0 8px}.intl-tel-input .selected-flag .iti-flag{position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;margin:auto}.intl-tel-input .selected-flag .iti-arrow{position:absolute;top:50%;margin-top:-2px;right:6px;width:0;height:0;border-left:3px solid transparent;border-right:3px solid transparent;border-top:4px solid #555}.intl-tel-input .selected-flag .iti-arrow.up{border-top:none;border-bottom:4px solid #555}.intl-tel-input .country-list{position:absolute;z-index:2;list-style:none;text-align:left;padding:0;margin:0 0 0 -1px;box-shadow:1px 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);background-color:#fff;border:1px solid #CCC;white-space:nowrap;max-height:200px;overflow-y:scroll}.intl-tel-input .country-list .country.highlight,.intl-tel-input.allow-dropdown .flag-container:hover .selected-flag{background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.05)}.intl-tel-input .country-list.dropup{bottom:100%;margin-bottom:-1px}.intl-tel-input .country-list .flag-box{display:inline-block;width:20px}@media (max-width:500px){.intl-tel-input .country-list{white-space:normal}}.intl-tel-input .country-list .divider{padding-bottom:5px;margin-bottom:5px;border-bottom:1px solid #CCC}.intl-tel-input .country-list .country{padding:5px 10px}.intl-tel-input .country-list .country .dial-code{color:#999}.intl-tel-input .country-list .country-name,.intl-tel-input .country-list .dial-code,.intl-tel-input .country-list .flag-box{vertical-align:middle}.intl-tel-input .country-list .country-name,.intl-tel-input .country-list .flag-box{margin-right:6px}.intl-tel-input.allow-dropdown input,.intl-tel-input.allow-dropdown input[type=tel],.intl-tel-input.allow-dropdown input[type=text],.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code input,.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code input[type=tel],.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code input[type=text]{padding-right:6px;padding-left:52px;margin-left:0}.intl-tel-input.allow-dropdown .flag-container,.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code .flag-container{right:auto;left:0}.intl-tel-input.allow-dropdown .selected-flag,.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code .selected-flag{width:46px}.intl-tel-input.allow-dropdown .flag-container:hover{cursor:pointer}.intl-tel-input.allow-dropdown input[disabled]+.flag-container:hover,.intl-tel-input.allow-dropdown input[readonly]+.flag-container:hover{cursor:default}.intl-tel-input.allow-dropdown input[disabled]+.flag-container:hover .selected-flag,.intl-tel-input.allow-dropdown input[readonly]+.flag-container:hover .selected-flag{background-color:transparent}.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code .selected-flag{background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.05);display:table}.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code .selected-dial-code{display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;padding-left:28px}.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.iti-sdc-2 input,.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.iti-sdc-2 input[type=tel],.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.iti-sdc-2 input[type=text]{padding-left:66px}.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.iti-sdc-2 .selected-flag{width:60px}.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.allow-dropdown.iti-sdc-2 input,.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.allow-dropdown.iti-sdc-2 input[type=tel],.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.allow-dropdown.iti-sdc-2 input[type=text]{padding-left:76px}.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.allow-dropdown.iti-sdc-2 .selected-flag{width:70px}.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.iti-sdc-3 input,.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.iti-sdc-3 input[type=tel],.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.iti-sdc-3 input[type=text]{padding-left:74px}.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.iti-sdc-3 .selected-flag{width:68px}.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.allow-dropdown.iti-sdc-3 input,.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.allow-dropdown.iti-sdc-3 input[type=tel],.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.allow-dropdown.iti-sdc-3 input[type=text]{padding-left:84px}.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.allow-dropdown.iti-sdc-3 .selected-flag{width:78px}.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.iti-sdc-4 input,.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.iti-sdc-4 input[type=tel],.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.iti-sdc-4 input[type=text]{padding-left:82px}.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.iti-sdc-4 .selected-flag{width:76px}.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.allow-dropdown.iti-sdc-4 input,.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.allow-dropdown.iti-sdc-4 input[type=tel],.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.allow-dropdown.iti-sdc-4 input[type=text]{padding-left:92px}.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.allow-dropdown.iti-sdc-4 .selected-flag{width:86px}.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.iti-sdc-5 input,.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.iti-sdc-5 input[type=tel],.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.iti-sdc-5 input[type=text]{padding-left:90px}.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.iti-sdc-5 .selected-flag{width:84px}.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.allow-dropdown.iti-sdc-5 input,.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.allow-dropdown.iti-sdc-5 input[type=tel],.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.allow-dropdown.iti-sdc-5 input[type=text]{padding-left:100px}.intl-tel-input.separate-dial-code.allow-dropdown.iti-sdc-5 .selected-flag{width:94px}.intl-tel-input.iti-container{position:absolute;top:-1000px;left:-1000px;z-index:1060;padding:1px}.intl-tel-input.iti-container:hover{cursor:pointer}.iti-mobile .intl-tel-input.iti-container{top:30px;bottom:30px;left:30px;right:30px;position:fixed}.iti-mobile .intl-tel-input .country-list{max-height:100%;width:100%}.iti-mobile .intl-tel-input .country-list .country{padding:10px;line-height:1.5em}.iti-flag{width:20px}.iti-flag.be{width:18px}.iti-flag.ch{width:15px}.iti-flag.mc{width:19px}.iti-flag.ne{width:18px}.iti-flag.ac{height:10px;background-position:0 0}.iti-flag.ad{height:14px;background-position:-22px 0}.iti-flag.ae{height:10px;background-position:-44px 0}.iti-flag.af{height:14px;background-position:-66px 0}.iti-flag.ag{height:14px;background-position:-88px 0}.iti-flag.ai{height:10px;background-position:-110px 0}.iti-flag.al{height:15px;background-position:-132px 0}.iti-flag.am{height:10px;background-position:-154px 0}.iti-flag.ao{height:14px;background-position:-176px 0}.iti-flag.aq{height:14px;background-position:-198px 0}.iti-flag.ar{height:13px;background-position:-220px 0}.iti-flag.as{height:10px;background-position:-242px 0}.iti-flag.at{height:14px;background-position:-264px 0}.iti-flag.au{height:10px;background-position:-286px 0}.iti-flag.aw{height:14px;background-position:-308px 0}.iti-flag.ax{height:13px;background-position:-330px 0}.iti-flag.az{height:10px;background-position:-352px 0}.iti-flag.ba{height:10px;background-position:-374px 0}.iti-flag.bb{height:14px;background-position:-396px 0}.iti-flag.bd{height:12px;background-position:-418px 0}.iti-flag.be{height:15px;background-position:-440px 0}.iti-flag.bf{height:14px;background-position:-460px 0}.iti-flag.bg{height:12px;background-position:-482px 0}.iti-flag.bh{height:12px;background-position:-504px 0}.iti-flag.bi{height:12px;background-position:-526px 0}.iti-flag.bj{height:14px;background-position:-548px 0}.iti-flag.bl{height:14px;background-position:-570px 0}.iti-flag.bm{height:10px;background-position:-592px 0}.iti-flag.bn{height:10px;background-position:-614px 0}.iti-flag.bo{height:14px;background-position:-636px 0}.iti-flag.bq{height:14px;background-position:-658px 0}.iti-flag.br{height:14px;background-position:-680px 0}.iti-flag.bs{height:10px;background-position:-702px 0}.iti-flag.bt{height:14px;background-position:-724px 0}.iti-flag.bv{height:15px;background-position:-746px 0}.iti-flag.bw{height:14px;background-position:-768px 0}.iti-flag.by{height:10px;background-position:-790px 0}.iti-flag.bz{height:14px;background-position:-812px 0}.iti-flag.ca{height:10px;background-position:-834px 0}.iti-flag.cc{height:10px;background-position:-856px 0}.iti-flag.cd{height:15px;background-position:-878px 0}.iti-flag.cf{height:14px;background-position:-900px 0}.iti-flag.cg{height:14px;background-position:-922px 0}.iti-flag.ch{height:15px;background-position:-944px 0}.iti-flag.ci{height:14px;background-position:-961px 0}.iti-flag.ck{height:10px;background-position:-983px 0}.iti-flag.cl{height:14px;background-position:-1005px 0}.iti-flag.cm{height:14px;background-position:-1027px 0}.iti-flag.cn{height:14px;background-position:-1049px 0}.iti-flag.co{height:14px;background-position:-1071px 0}.iti-flag.cp{height:14px;background-position:-1093px 0}.iti-flag.cr{height:12px;background-position:-1115px 0}.iti-flag.cu{height:10px;background-position:-1137px 0}.iti-flag.cv{height:12px;background-position:-1159px 0}.iti-flag.cw{height:14px;background-position:-1181px 0}.iti-flag.cx{height:10px;background-position:-1203px 0}.iti-flag.cy{height:13px;background-position:-1225px 0}.iti-flag.cz{height:14px;background-position:-1247px 0}.iti-flag.de{height:12px;background-position:-1269px 0}.iti-flag.dg{height:10px;background-position:-1291px 0}.iti-flag.dj{height:14px;background-position:-1313px 0}.iti-flag.dk{height:15px;background-position:-1335px 0}.iti-flag.dm{height:10px;background-position:-1357px 0}.iti-flag.do{height:13px;background-position:-1379px 0}.iti-flag.dz{height:14px;background-position:-1401px 0}.iti-flag.ea{height:14px;background-position:-1423px 0}.iti-flag.ec{height:14px;background-position:-1445px 0}.iti-flag.ee{height:13px;background-position:-1467px 0}.iti-flag.eg{height:14px;background-position:-1489px 0}.iti-flag.eh{height:10px;background-position:-1511px 0}.iti-flag.er{height:10px;background-position:-1533px 0}.iti-flag.es{height:14px;background-position:-1555px 0}.iti-flag.et{height:10px;background-position:-1577px 0}.iti-flag.eu{height:14px;background-position:-1599px 0}.iti-flag.fi{height:12px;background-position:-1621px 0}.iti-flag.fj{height:10px;background-position:-1643px 0}.iti-flag.fk{height:10px;background-position:-1665px 0}.iti-flag.fm{height:11px;background-position:-1687px 0}.iti-flag.fo{height:15px;background-position:-1709px 0}.iti-flag.fr{height:14px;background-position:-1731px 0}.iti-flag.ga{height:15px;background-position:-1753px 0}.iti-flag.gb{height:10px;background-position:-1775px 0}.iti-flag.gd{height:12px;background-position:-1797px 0}.iti-flag.ge{height:14px;background-position:-1819px 0}.iti-flag.gf{height:14px;background-position:-1841px 0}.iti-flag.gg{height:14px;background-position:-1863px 0}.iti-flag.gh{height:14px;background-position:-1885px 0}.iti-flag.gi{height:10px;background-position:-1907px 0}.iti-flag.gl{height:14px;background-position:-1929px 0}.iti-flag.gm{height:14px;background-position:-1951px 0}.iti-flag.gn{height:14px;background-position:-1973px 0}.iti-flag.gp{height:14px;background-position:-1995px 0}.iti-flag.gq{height:14px;background-position:-2017px 0}.iti-flag.gr{height:14px;background-position:-2039px 0}.iti-flag.gs{height:10px;background-position:-2061px 0}.iti-flag.gt{height:13px;background-position:-2083px 0}.iti-flag.gu{height:11px;background-position:-2105px 0}.iti-flag.gw{height:10px;background-position:-2127px 0}.iti-flag.gy{height:12px;background-position:-2149px 0}.iti-flag.hk{height:14px;background-position:-2171px 0}.iti-flag.hm{height:10px;background-position:-2193px 0}.iti-flag.hn{height:10px;background-position:-2215px 0}.iti-flag.hr{height:10px;background-position:-2237px 0}.iti-flag.ht{height:12px;background-position:-2259px 0}.iti-flag.hu{height:10px;background-position:-2281px 0}.iti-flag.ic{height:14px;background-position:-2303px 0}.iti-flag.id{height:14px;background-position:-2325px 0}.iti-flag.ie{height:10px;background-position:-2347px 0}.iti-flag.il{height:15px;background-position:-2369px 0}.iti-flag.im{height:10px;background-position:-2391px 0}.iti-flag.in{height:14px;background-position:-2413px 0}.iti-flag.io{height:10px;background-position:-2435px 0}.iti-flag.iq{height:14px;background-position:-2457px 0}.iti-flag.ir{height:12px;background-position:-2479px 0}.iti-flag.is{height:15px;background-position:-2501px 0}.iti-flag.it{height:14px;background-position:-2523px 0}.iti-flag.je{height:12px;background-position:-2545px 0}.iti-flag.jm{height:10px;background-position:-2567px 0}.iti-flag.jo{height:10px;background-position:-2589px 0}.iti-flag.jp{height:14px;background-position:-2611px 0}.iti-flag.ke{height:14px;background-position:-2633px 0}.iti-flag.kg{height:12px;background-position:-2655px 0}.iti-flag.kh{height:13px;background-position:-2677px 0}.iti-flag.ki{height:10px;background-position:-2699px 0}.iti-flag.km{height:12px;background-position:-2721px 0}.iti-flag.kn{height:14px;background-position:-2743px 0}.iti-flag.kp{height:10px;background-position:-2765px 0}.iti-flag.kr{height:14px;background-position:-2787px 0}.iti-flag.kw{height:10px;background-position:-2809px 0}.iti-flag.ky{height:10px;background-position:-2831px 0}.iti-flag.kz{height:10px;background-position:-2853px 0}.iti-flag.la{height:14px;background-position:-2875px 0}.iti-flag.lb{height:14px;background-position:-2897px 0}.iti-flag.lc{height:10px;background-position:-2919px 0}.iti-flag.li{height:12px;background-position:-2941px 0}.iti-flag.lk{height:10px;background-position:-2963px 0}.iti-flag.lr{height:11px;background-position:-2985px 0}.iti-flag.ls{height:14px;background-position:-3007px 0}.iti-flag.lt{height:12px;background-position:-3029px 0}.iti-flag.lu{height:12px;background-position:-3051px 0}.iti-flag.lv{height:10px;background-position:-3073px 0}.iti-flag.ly{height:10px;background-position:-3095px 0}.iti-flag.ma{height:14px;background-position:-3117px 0}.iti-flag.mc{height:15px;background-position:-3139px 0}.iti-flag.md{height:10px;background-position:-3160px 0}.iti-flag.me{height:10px;background-position:-3182px 0}.iti-flag.mf{height:14px;background-position:-3204px 0}.iti-flag.mg{height:14px;background-position:-3226px 0}.iti-flag.mh{height:11px;background-position:-3248px 0}.iti-flag.mk{height:10px;background-position:-3270px 0}.iti-flag.ml{height:14px;background-position:-3292px 0}.iti-flag.mm{height:14px;background-position:-3314px 0}.iti-flag.mn{height:10px;background-position:-3336px 0}.iti-flag.mo{height:14px;background-position:-3358px 0}.iti-flag.mp{height:10px;background-position:-3380px 0}.iti-flag.mq{height:14px;background-position:-3402px 0}.iti-flag.mr{height:14px;background-position:-3424px 0}.iti-flag.ms{height:10px;background-position:-3446px 0}.iti-flag.mt{height:14px;background-position:-3468px 0}.iti-flag.mu{height:14px;background-position:-3490px 0}.iti-flag.mv{height:14px;background-position:-3512px 0}.iti-flag.mw{height:14px;background-position:-3534px 0}.iti-flag.mx{height:12px;background-position:-3556px 0}.iti-flag.my{height:10px;background-position:-3578px 0}.iti-flag.mz{height:14px;background-position:-3600px 0}.iti-flag.na{height:14px;background-position:-3622px 0}.iti-flag.nc{height:10px;background-position:-3644px 0}.iti-flag.ne{height:15px;background-position:-3666px 0}.iti-flag.nf{height:10px;background-position:-3686px 0}.iti-flag.ng{height:10px;background-position:-3708px 0}.iti-flag.ni{height:12px;background-position:-3730px 0}.iti-flag.nl{height:14px;background-position:-3752px 0}.iti-flag.no{height:15px;background-position:-3774px 0}.iti-flag.np{width:13px;height:15px;background-position:-3796px 0}.iti-flag.nr{height:10px;background-position:-3811px 0}.iti-flag.nu{height:10px;background-position:-3833px 0}.iti-flag.nz{height:10px;background-position:-3855px 0}.iti-flag.om{height:10px;background-position:-3877px 0}.iti-flag.pa{height:14px;background-position:-3899px 0}.iti-flag.pe{height:14px;background-position:-3921px 0}.iti-flag.pf{height:14px;background-position:-3943px 0}.iti-flag.pg{height:15px;background-position:-3965px 0}.iti-flag.ph{height:10px;background-position:-3987px 0}.iti-flag.pk{height:14px;background-position:-4009px 0}.iti-flag.pl{height:13px;background-position:-4031px 0}.iti-flag.pm{height:14px;background-position:-4053px 0}.iti-flag.pn{height:10px;background-position:-4075px 0}.iti-flag.pr{height:14px;background-position:-4097px 0}.iti-flag.ps{height:10px;background-position:-4119px 0}.iti-flag.pt{height:14px;background-position:-4141px 0}.iti-flag.pw{height:13px;background-position:-4163px 0}.iti-flag.py{height:11px;background-position:-4185px 0}.iti-flag.qa{height:8px;background-position:-4207px 0}.iti-flag.re{height:14px;background-position:-4229px 0}.iti-flag.ro{height:14px;background-position:-4251px 0}.iti-flag.rs{height:14px;background-position:-4273px 0}.iti-flag.ru{height:14px;background-position:-4295px 0}.iti-flag.rw{height:14px;background-position:-4317px 0}.iti-flag.sa{height:14px;background-position:-4339px 0}.iti-flag.sb{height:10px;background-position:-4361px 0}.iti-flag.sc{height:10px;background-position:-4383px 0}.iti-flag.sd{height:10px;background-position:-4405px 0}.iti-flag.se{height:13px;background-position:-4427px 0}.iti-flag.sg{height:14px;background-position:-4449px 0}.iti-flag.sh{height:10px;background-position:-4471px 0}.iti-flag.si{height:10px;background-position:-4493px 0}.iti-flag.sj{height:15px;background-position:-4515px 0}.iti-flag.sk{height:14px;background-position:-4537px 0}.iti-flag.sl{height:14px;background-position:-4559px 0}.iti-flag.sm{height:15px;background-position:-4581px 0}.iti-flag.sn{height:14px;background-position:-4603px 0}.iti-flag.so{height:14px;background-position:-4625px 0}.iti-flag.sr{height:14px;background-position:-4647px 0}.iti-flag.ss{height:10px;background-position:-4669px 0}.iti-flag.st{height:10px;background-position:-4691px 0}.iti-flag.sv{height:12px;background-position:-4713px 0}.iti-flag.sx{height:14px;background-position:-4735px 0}.iti-flag.sy{height:14px;background-position:-4757px 0}.iti-flag.sz{height:14px;background-position:-4779px 0}.iti-flag.ta{height:10px;background-position:-4801px 0}.iti-flag.tc{height:10px;background-position:-4823px 0}.iti-flag.td{height:14px;background-position:-4845px 0}.iti-flag.tf{height:14px;background-position:-4867px 0}.iti-flag.tg{height:13px;background-position:-4889px 0}.iti-flag.th{height:14px;background-position:-4911px 0}.iti-flag.tj{height:10px;background-position:-4933px 0}.iti-flag.tk{height:10px;background-position:-4955px 0}.iti-flag.tl{height:10px;background-position:-4977px 0}.iti-flag.tm{height:14px;background-position:-4999px 0}.iti-flag.tn{height:14px;background-position:-5021px 0}.iti-flag.to{height:10px;background-position:-5043px 0}.iti-flag.tr{height:14px;background-position:-5065px 0}.iti-flag.tt{height:12px;background-position:-5087px 0}.iti-flag.tv{height:10px;background-position:-5109px 0}.iti-flag.tw{height:14px;background-position:-5131px 0}.iti-flag.tz{height:14px;background-position:-5153px 0}.iti-flag.ua{height:14px;background-position:-5175px 0}.iti-flag.ug{height:14px;background-position:-5197px 0}.iti-flag.um{height:11px;background-position:-5219px 0}.iti-flag.us{height:11px;background-position:-5241px 0}.iti-flag.uy{height:14px;background-position:-5263px 0}.iti-flag.uz{height:10px;background-position:-5285px 0}.iti-flag.va{width:15px;height:15px;background-position:-5307px 0}.iti-flag.vc{height:14px;background-position:-5324px 0}.iti-flag.ve{height:14px;background-position:-5346px 0}.iti-flag.vg{height:10px;background-position:-5368px 0}.iti-flag.vi{height:14px;background-position:-5390px 0}.iti-flag.vn{height:14px;background-position:-5412px 0}.iti-flag.vu{height:12px;background-position:-5434px 0}.iti-flag.wf{height:14px;background-position:-5456px 0}.iti-flag.ws{height:10px;background-position:-5478px 0}.iti-flag.xk{height:15px;background-position:-5500px 0}.iti-flag.ye{height:14px;background-position:-5522px 0}.iti-flag.yt{height:14px;background-position:-5544px 0}.iti-flag.za{height:14px;background-position:-5566px 0}.iti-flag.zm{height:14px;background-position:-5588px 0}.iti-flag.zw{height:10px;background-position:-5610px 0}.iti-flag{height:15px;box-shadow:0 0 1px 0 #888;background-image:url(../images/flags.png);background-repeat:no-repeat;background-color:#DBDBDB;background-position:20px 0}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2),only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio:2),only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio:2 / 1),only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio:2),only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi),only screen and (min-resolution:2dppx){.iti-flag{background-size:5630px 15px;background-image:url(../images/flags@2x.png)}}.iti-flag.np{background-color:transparent}
```

[check out image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ho0Mt.png)